# Can entity framework handle Type 2 slowly changing dimensions?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-warehouse

First off...apologies if this is a really dumb question!

I have developed a CRM type application using C# web forms that updates records in our company database. Some areas of the DB use type 2 slowly changing dimensions (SCD) and my application uses stored procedures to read and update these SCDs.

I would like to move our application from web forms to MVC and the PluralSight course I am doing has a large section on Entity Framework (EF) using tables, but nothing about SCDs.

EF looks great for easy CRUD on "normal" tables and I am keen to utilise it when I recreate our CRM system in MVC.

My question is, can EF handle the tables in our DB that use SCDs or should I only use it for the ones that don't?

Comment: SCD updates are just updates to existing rows and inserts of new rows, so you could use EF for it the same way as normal. But you'd need to be controlling that, EF wouldn't have anything built in to do it for you.

Comment: Not a dumb question at all - been struggling myself.
I have posted a more generic version with worked example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372560/net-orm-framework-with-data-versioning-slowly-changing-dimension-type-2