# .NET ORM Framework with data versioning (Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2)?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, scd

I am building a .NET application for inserting data (an Excel add-in in fact), and I want to use an ORM for inserting data **with automated versioning**.

Here's a worked example:

- User "John Doe" does the first data insertion (4 data points as per below example)
- At a later time, user "Albert" opens the interface, modifies one data point, and saves
- All 4 data points are processed; ORM flags the modified data as non-Current, adds the new data, updates version counter, changes validity dates columns

[image: JOHNDOE and ALBERT insert data one after the other...]

I am looking for an ORM framework that would automatically take care of the versioning.
Below, the database table after the second insertion.
Those familiar with DB schemas will recognize this as a "Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) Type 2"

[image]

The data will be accessed not via the ORM, but from various SQL queries, so the valid_from/valid_to columns are essentials.
I am also aware that this can be done with database triggers but I want a solution that works regardless of back-end...

Comment: This is typically a data warehouse concept. Wouldn't populating this table be part of an ETL procedure, which generally isn't carried out bij ORMs?

Comment: This is more of a CRUD input situation with versioning/change tracking.
ETLs have extensive libraries for this, but you can't really integrate SSIS/Talend/Pentaho withing a .NET context.
I can't see how the most popular .NET ORMs don't have a feature for this?

Comment: So, either you want us to provide you with a link to a library (off topic) or the answer is "sit down and start programming and come back and ask when you have tried SOMETHING - and without trying, also off topic. This is a fringe requirement - so not in standard tools. Most people will use triggers or db means (i.e. SQL Server has temporal tables that do exactly that now as database core function). And ORM are a QUITE bad solution for most ETL needs - sorry. Performance will b bad unless data size is smallish.

Comment: I am aware of DB triggers - it is not the solution here, as I'm looking for a database-neutral solution. Also aware of SQL-Server temporal tables, but again, I want the project to be SQL-dialect-neutral. This is an Excel add-in, not an ETL project (as per description), so the data workflow would be small, and performance not an issue. Re doing my work, I have done a workaround based on dynamic SQL merge statement, but this is clearly not a the generalized solution I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found something.

NHibernate has a versioning extension, Envers.

http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-envers-quick-introduction

It will create both last-version tables and versioned tables.
It won't call it a "Slowly Changing Dimension", but the versioning strategy is equivalent (as opposed to creating a table for each measure to version)

Schema below.

[image: Example Schema]